# Angular Universal: lazy loaded modules initialised before APP_INITIALIZER

Tags: angular, angular-universal

My app uses `APP_INITIALIZER` to dynamically retrieve some config from a json file before initialising the application.

When using angular universal, lazy loaded modules are created on server side before the promised returned when using `APP_INITIALIZER` has resolved.

This works fine when not using angular universal. Is this a bug from angular universal, or am I doing something wrong?

**app.module.ts**

```
export function loadConfigService(configService: AppConfigService): Function
{
  return () => {
    return configService.load();
  };
}

@NgModule({
    //...
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: loadConfigService,
      deps: [AppConfigService],
      multi: true
    },
```

**app-config.service.ts**

```
export class AppConfig
{

  readonly apiUrl: string;
  //other properties
}


export let APP_CONFIG: AppConfig;

@Injectable()
export class AppConfigService
{


  constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object, @Optional() @Inject('serverUrl') protected serverUrl: string)
  {
  }

  public load()
  {
    console.log('in load');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      const isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId);

      let baseUrl = isBrowser ? '' : this.serverUrl;

      this.http.get(`${baseUrl}/assets/config/conf.json`).pipe(catchError((error: any): any => {
        reject(error);
        return observableThrowError('Server error');
      })).subscribe((envResponse: any) => {
        let t = new AppConfig();

        APP_CONFIG = Object.assign(t, envResponse);
        console.log('in response');
        resolve(true);
      });

    });
  }
}
```

**Child module**

```
import {APP_CONFIG} from "@utils/services/app-config.service";

export class LazyChildModule
{
  constructor()
  {
   console.log('in child constructor');
   //Here, APP_CONFIG is null
```

Output without universal:

```
in load
in response
in child constructor
```

Output with universal:

```
in load
in child constructor
in response
```

Comment: This is still an issue, did you get around it?

Comment: @ayyash I had to use a workaround with the config service emitting an event when it's ready, so that i can use the config object in the child module.